# How to convert result created with dupliverts into editable meshes?

Tags: mesh

[image]

Hi, I have this Cylinder and Cube. Cylinder is parented to the Cube and duplicated as you can see in the right down corner (option "verts"). Now I don't know how to convert the duplicated Cylinders to meshes, so I could have one mesh. Now when I switch to edit mode I still have only one Cylinder and the duplicated eight are not real meshes but only duplications. Do you know how to fix it?
Sry for my english ... .

Comment: have you tried duplicating with an array-modifier?

Answer (score 12):

You can use the "Make Duplicates Real" function <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>. This will generate one object for each duplicate, but the generated objets will still share the same mesh. You can join them <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd> to make a single mesh with all the cylinders. You can then separate each to an object with its own mesh by going to edit mode and <kbd>P</kbd> "By loose parts".

Comment: I have to say that the phrase "have one mesh" in the question is pretty ambiguous.  Depending on exactly what Ryšavý wants, he may or may not need to joins and separates.  Sharing a mesh is often a good thing.

Comment: you can always link those objects' data (Ctrl+L)

Comment: Blender 2.83 now calls this "Make Instances Real"